# create new dataframes based on an old dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with this schema and would like to create many dataframes based on how many distinct Icao that we have, can anyone help?
First, I create an array.

```
val icao = test.select(test("Icao")).distinct
```

then, I need to do a `for-loop` to create dataframes based on the "where clause"

```
scala> test.printSchema()
root
 |-- Icao: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Alt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Long: double (nullable = true)
 |-- PosTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Spd: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Trak: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Op: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Cou: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: While you certainly _could_ do this, it seems kind of contrary to the usual way of using dataframes in Spark.  Are you sure that you really need to create a data-dependent number of dataframes?

Comment: I think a better approach would be to use `df.partitionBy("Icao").write`

Comment: Each Icao represents a unique aircraft, my goal is to take each aircraft flight path and display on a map with timestamp vs Lag, Long, any good solutions?

Comment: Why would you want to separate dataframe into multiple dataframes in order to just create maps ? Can you elaborate on your requirement of creating map?